# How can a maven plugin provide a file to another?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

We have a maven plugin that's basically a wrapper around the maven-assembly-plugin. We do things like:

```
    executeMojo(
            assemblyPlugin,
            goal("single"),
            configuration(
                    element(name("descriptor"), descriptor),
                    element(name("formats"), element(name("format"), "tar.gz")),
            ),
            executionEnvironment(mavenProject, mavenSession, pluginManager)
    )
```

(Yes, it's groovy.)

The location of the `descriptor` is still passed as a parameter from the project that includes this plugin. However, we'd like to provide at least a default file and pass that reference to the maven-assembly-plugin.

If we package a descriptor file with our plugin, where does it end up? What kind of path can we give to the assembly plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In maven assembly plugin exists a concept of shared descriptor...see the docs. If this not fit describe more in detail what you like to achieve and why you are using a wrapper around maven-assembly-plugin...

Comment: That would work, the plugin project can deploy a shared descriptor that it then uses. Would you like to add an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the concept of [shared descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/sharing-descriptors.html) which is supported by the maven-assembly-plugin.